# How to return only one part of the data?

Tags: node.js, json

I run the code below and it brings back a lot of data but I only want to return the account name, which is listed as 'acct' in the data. To give you a clear idea of the data, I've copied/pasted some of it here, and blanked out any identifying info in order to protect people's privacy http://txt.do/11pf6

tried console logging different parameters but it didn't work

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://SiteImScraping.com/api/v1/timelines/public',
    json: true,
};


request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('headers', res.headers);
    console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)); 
    for(i in obj) {
    console.log(i['account']);
    }
    console.log(obj);
});
```

**EDIT**: I changed the code to the following, and now it only returns the parameter I need from the JSON data. Thanks for the suggestions!

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://siteParsed.com/api/v1/timelines/public',
    json: true,
};


request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }

    obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));

    for(i in obj) {
    console.log(obj[i].account.acct);
    }

});
```

Comment: FYI, `for(i in obj)` gets you a sequence of property names on `obj`.  To access the value of one of those properties, you have to do `obj[i]` or `obj[i].account`, not `i['account']`.

Comment: Also, the `json:true` option for `request()`  automatically parses the JSON for you, so you don't need to.  If the response is proper JSON, then `body` will already be the parsed JSON.  So, get rid of the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)`.  You can just directly access `body.someProperty` if the response was proper JSON.

Comment: Thanks jfriend, your solution worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply access it as if it was an object:

```
obj.account.acct
```

Pro tip, use something like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to more easily view JSON

Comment: thanks, i'll use that json site next time. When you say access it as if it were an object, where do we access it from in the code? I tried console logging with that but it threw an error

Comment: It depends on the output of your request, right after:


obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));

you should be able to access obj as a regular JS object

Answer (score 0):

change
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));

to 
obj = JSON.parse(body);

then you can be able to traverse through the data like;
obj.level1.level2.level3

Comment: The `json:true` option for `request()` already parses a JSON response for you automatically.  No need for `JSON.parse()` at all.

Comment: That didn't cross my mind. Thanks too for the correction.